# Can I implement backend processes without database?

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend

I'm a js developer and would like to create a one page application, where several users  are creating a common list.

The idea is that everyone can see what others added/removed. The biggest question is: 'can I handle it without implementing any backend processes?'
All I can think of is to create database and connect with it using API.

> Is there an easier way. There is just going to be max 10 people involved, adding small pieces of text. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think, a backend application, if you do not want to use the database, use a simple API server, where store all data in a file (Expose API for CRUD)

Comment: *store all data in a file* - i.e. the simplest form of database. `can I handle it without implementing any backend processes` - no, unless you want to write some sort of direct client to client communication, but even that requires some sort of backend so clients can know about each other ... there has to be a backend process of some sort

Comment: use the database or not. you at least need a data storage such as a file to store user data or other data permanently. however instead of using files I would recommend sticking with the database as you don't have to worry about data integrity. if you don't have access to install database you can use sqlite database

Comment: @JaromandaX, I think it is not possible to store the data in a file from the front-end application because you can't use the fs module in the code that is rendered in the browser.

Comment: The simple way to do this is use firebase, it will do all work for you. refer this link may be it will helpful to you [firebase serverless](https://medium.com/@charpellumeh/build-a-serverless-full-stack-app-using-firebase-cloud-functions-81afe34a64fc)

Comment: @BennisonJ - thanks for incorrecting me ... I never mentioned front-end at all ... I said "there has to be a backend process of some sort" in case you misread it

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's  possible. You can use the browser's local storage to store the common list data, and JavaScript to handle the logic for adding, removing, and updating items. For real-time communication, you can use WebSockets or a real-time platforms like Firebase's Realtime Database or Pusher.

Implement synchronization logic to handle conflicts and ensure that all users have the most up-to-date version of the list. This approach has limitations in terms of storage capacity, and user management compared to a backend database, but it's possible.